# How to query hundreds of indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a log system and the everyday a new index will be created.
Now, I have to do querys for a whole year, that is 365 indices.

Although ES has `date math` support for index names, it seems that I have to write a query like this:

`GET /<logstash-{now/d}>,<logstash-{now/d-1d}>,<logstash-{now/d-2d}>,...
......
there will be 365 items for each day
......
/_search`

Is threr a better way to query?

Comment: Do you any other indexes with the name logstash in ES?

Comment: Check out these docs on date math support in index names - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html

Answer (score 0):

You can query multiple indices with a wildcard in Elasticsearch. Documentation can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html).

For example, if your indices were all named `logstash-{date}`, you could query `localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search` and that would query every index that matches the pattern.

If you *only* want to query indices within a one year time period, you can use a range query on the date field in the index (if you're using the Logstash default it will be `@timestamp`). Documentation on range queries can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html).